# apache port changed after reboot

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

My server get rebooted last night (Probably due to some DC issues) . But after the reboot apache port changed from 80 to 8080  in configuration file.I'm not using any control panels. What should be the reason. ? I really confused and first time I'm seeing these kind of issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex, the default ports for Apache are 80 *HTTP* and 443 *HTTPS*.  These are compile time default options.  Unless you compiled apache with different defaults, then the only way your server would be listening on 8080 is if either you or someone else added a Listen directive to do so.

You can grep through your config files for 8080 and then get the timestamp of the config file.  Compare the time stamp with the last people that logged into the server via the "lastlog" command.

It is possible this change was made some time ago and you forgot about it, thus resulting in a *landmine*; so to speak, that activated when your server was rebooted last night.

Comment: Listen as well as all <VirtualHost *:80> entries changed to <VirtualHost *:8080> . I'm not seeing any logins at that time. Really confused !

Comment: as root, netstat -aeenp | grep 8080  that will show you the daemon listening on 8080.  If you did not change it, someone else did for you.